# ElasticSearch Java API:NoNodeAvailableException: No node available

Tags: java, elasticsearch

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
            .put("cluster.name", "foxzen")
            .put("node.name", "yu").build();
    Client client = new TransportClient(settings)
            .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", 9200));
            // XXX is my server's ip address
    IndexResponse response = client.prepareIndex("twitter", "tweet")
            .setSource(XContentFactory.jsonBuilder()
                    .startObject()
                    .field("productId", "1")
                    .field("productName", "XXX").endObject()).execute().actionGet();
    System.out.println(response.getIndex());
    System.out.println(response.getType());
    System.out.println(response.getVersion());
    client.close();
}
```

I access server from my computer

```
curl -get http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9200/
```

get this

```
{
    "status" : 200,
    "name" : "yu",
    "version" : {
        "number" : "1.1.0",
        "build_hash" : "2181e113dea80b4a9e31e58e9686658a2d46e363",
        "build_timestamp" : "2014-03-25T15:59:51Z",
        "build_snapshot" : false,
        "lucene_version" : "4.7"
    },
    "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Why get error by using Java API?

**EDIT**

There is the cluster and node part config of `elasticsearch.yml`

```
################################### Cluster ###################################

# Cluster name identifies your cluster for auto-discovery. If you're running
# multiple clusters on the same network, make sure you're using unique names.
#
cluster.name: foxzen


#################################### Node #####################################

# Node names are generated dynamically on startup, so you're relieved
# from configuring them manually. You can tie this node to a specific name:
#
node.name: yu
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Some suggestions:

1 - Use port 9300. [9300-9400] is for node-to-node communication, [9200-9300] is for HTTP traffic.

2 - Ensure the version of the Java API you are using matches the version of elasticsearch running on the server.

3 - Ensure that the name of your cluster is `foxzen` (check the elasticsearch.yml on the server).

4 - Remove `put("node.name", "yu")`, you aren't joining the cluster as a node since you are using the `TransportClient`, and even if you were it appears your server node is named `yu` so you would want a different node name in any case.

Comment: the ElasticSearch Java API version is 0.19.9. I dont know how to check the version of ElasticSearch server

Comment: Can you check the install dir on the server, just look in the install directories lib folder and see what version the elasticsearch jar is. There is probably a way to get the version via curl but I can't think of it off the top of my head (and if I could I wouldn't trust it to work on a version that old anyways).

Comment: Your server is running Elasticsearch version 1.1.0 (it is the `"number": "1.1.0"` entry) in the response from your curl request you posted in the question.

Comment: Guess I'm blind. Upgrade your Java client to use the elasticsearch-1.1.0.jar per my 1st suggestion.

Comment: OK - looks like you are using the correct cluster name based on your edit. Have you tried removing the 'put("node.name", "yu")' yet?

Comment: Yes, I have been tried every suggestion that you said. Its not working

Comment: Use port 9300, not 9200

Comment: OMG! Its working!! Why? I got the ElasticSearch info by execute `curl -get http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9200/` from my computer.

Comment: Sorry, not sure how I missed that at first. [9200-9300] is for HTTP traffic, [9300-9400] is for node-to-node (and transport client) communication. I've edited my answer to include this as well.

Comment: Thx for your patient very much!

Comment: Updating jar version to same as Server version worked for me

Comment: My problem was that I had this setting enabled: `.put("client.transport.sniff", true)`, after commenting that out - It found the nodes.

Comment: in my case,i had installed 5.0 on local setup and through maven I was using 0.90,so was getting this error,matched the ES version & it worked after so much struggle

Comment: @DanBarzilay- I solved my error by seeing your comment. Can you please explain more about it?

Answer (score 10):

You need to change your code to use port 9300 - correct line would be:

```
 Client client = new TransportClient(settings)
            .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", 9300));
```

The reason is that the Java API is using the internal transport used for inter node communications and it defaults to port 9300. Port 9200 is the default for the REST API interface. Common issue to run into - check this sample code here towards the bottom of the page, under Transport Client:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/client.html

```
// on startup

Client client = new TransportClient()
        .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("host1", 9300))
        .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("host2", 9300));

// on shutdown

client.close();
```

Answer (score 3):

I met this error too. I use ElasticSearch 2.4.1 as a standalone server (single node) in docker, programming with Grails 3/spring-data-elasticsearch. My fix is setting `client.transport.sniff` to `false`. Here is my core conf :

application.yml

```
spring.data.elasticsearch:
    cluster-name: "my-es"
    cluster-nodes: "localhost:9300"
    properties:
        "client.transport.ignore_cluster_name": true
        "client.transport.nodes_sampler_interval": "5s"
        "client.transport.ping_timeout": "5s"
        "client.transport.sniff": false      # XXX : notice here
    repositories.enabled: false
```

See [this](https://github.com/docker-library/elasticsearch/issues/38)

Comment: Referring to ES 2.4 docs (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/2.4/transport-client.html) , it seems to me that "client.transport.sniff" default is disabled - as the timeouts 5s. So the only actual modification here is the `cluster-name` and the `ignore_cluster_name`. I believe this configuration causes no effect (positive or negative) to the original problem `NoNodeAvailableException`.

Comment: @Beccari
You are right. I test the code, even I comment out `spring.data.elasticsearch.properties`, My code still work. The elasticsearch source code using the propertis is [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/2.4/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/client/transport/TransportClientNodesService.java#L123)。

I make a mistake same as  Dan Barzilay: had setting "client.transport.sniff" to true, then got `NoNodeAvailableException`.

This is not same as the original problem.  But maybe a reminder to others.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are setting the ES server on a remote host? In that case you will need to bind the publish address to the host's public IP address.

In your ES host edit `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml` and add its public IP after network.publish_host:

```
# Set the address other nodes will use to communicate with this node. If not
# set, it is automatically derived. It must point to an actual IP address.
#
network.publish_host: 192.168.0.1
```

And in your code connect to this host on port 9300. Note that you need the IP and not the domain name (at least according to my experience on Amazon EC2)

Comment: Thanks ! i had wrong configuration in my yml file. network.host: property was set to 0.0.0.0.

Changing it to 127.0.0.1 worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

If you are still having issues, even when using port 9300, and everything else seems to be configured correctly, try using an older version of elasticsearch.

I was getting this same error while using elasticsearch version 2.2.0, but as soon as I rolled back to version 1.7.5, my problem magically went away. Here's a link to someone else having this issue : [older version solves problem](http://frustrateddevelopers.com/2015/11/none-of-the-configured-nodes-are-available/?utm_campaign=shareaholic&utm_medium=google_plus&utm_source=socialnetwork)

Answer (score 0):

For folks with similar problems, I received this because I had not set `cluster.name` in the `TransportClient` builder. Added the property and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

Other reason could be, your *Elasticsearch Java client* is a different version from your *Elasticsearch server*.

Elasticsearch Java client version is nothing but your **elasticsearch** jar version in your code base.

For example: In my code it's **elasticsearch-2.4.0.jar**

To verify Elasticsearch server version,

```
$ /Users/kkolipaka/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -version
Version: 5.2.2, Build: f9d9b74/2017-02-24T17:26:45.835Z, JVM: 1.8.0_111
```

As you can see, I've downloaded latest version of Elastic server 5.2.2 but forgot to update the ES Java API client version 2.4.0
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/client.html

Answer (score 0):

Another solution may be to include `io.netty.netty-all` into project dependencies explicitly.

On `addTransportAddresses` a method `nodesSampler.sample()` is being executed, and added addresses are being checked for availability there.
In my case `try-catch` block swallows `ConnectTransportException` because a method `io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelId.newInstance()` cannot be found. So added node just isn't treated as available.