# org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException on indexing

Tags: java, elasticsearch

The call `client.index(indexRequest)` in the following code:

```
public static void main(String...sdg) {

    Settings s = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
            .put("cluster.name","myCluster")
            .build();
    TransportClient client = new TransportClient(s)
        .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("localhost", 9300));;
    try {
        IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest("myindex", "pplain", "29");    
        indexRequest.source(makeAJsonDocument("some title", "some content");
        client.index(indexRequest)
              .actionGet();
    } catch (Exception e) 
    { System.out.println("error \n"+e);
    e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {client.close();  
    }
}
```

is throwing the following error:

```
Jul 24, 2015 3:40:56 PM org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService <init>
INFO: [Ectokid] loaded [], sites []
error 
org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: []
org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: []
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(TransportClientNodesService.java:305)
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:200)
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.support.InternalTransportClient.execute(InternalTransportClient.java:106)
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.support.InternalTransportClient.execute(InternalTransportClient.java:97)
at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.index(AbstractClient.java:97)
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.index(TransportClient.java:335)
at ES.ThisPRJ.ThatClass.main(ThatClass.java:67)
```

My `elasticsearch.yml` looks like this:

```
cluster.name: myCluster
```

I'm running ES version 1.7.0 both on the server and on Java client-- I have only one installation of ES.

wore me out.

what am I missing???

Note: I saw [ElasticSearch Java API:NoNodeAvailableException: No node available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23520684/elasticsearch-java-apinonodeavailableexception-no-node-available) and some other posts.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

There is a small compilation problem in the code you provided, check the line where you do indexRequest.source, you are missing a ')'. I used this code and it works fine for me. Can you try it out? Did you leave out some of the code?

```
import org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexRequest;
import org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient;
import org.elasticsearch.common.settings.ImmutableSettings;
import org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings;
import org.elasticsearch.common.transport.InetSocketTransportAddress;

public class TestMe {
    public static void main(String... sdg) {

        Settings s = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
                .put("cluster.name", "performance")
                .build();
        TransportClient client = new TransportClient(s)
                .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("localhost", 9300));
        try {
            IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest("myindex", "pplain", "29");
            indexRequest.source("{\"title\":\"This is a title\"}");
            client.index(indexRequest)
                    .actionGet();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error \n" + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            client.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I guess you already verified if the cluster was running using the browser?
http://localhost:9200