# ElasticSearch 2.0 Transport Client - No Node Available exception

Tags: java, elasticsearch

[Using ElasticSearch version 2.0]

In etc/hosts file  "esnode" is mapped to IP address(some other machine where ES is running) as shown

192.168.2.219   esnode

The Transport Client code is ::

```
public Client getClient() { 
    if ((this.client == null)) { 
        try { 
            Settings settings = Settings.settingsBuilder() 
                    .put("cluster.name", "myclustername").build(); 
            TransportClient tClient = TransportClient.builder().settings(settings).build(); 
            String[] nodes = "esnode:9300".split(COMMA); 
            for (String node : nodes) { 
                String[] hostPort = node.split(COLON); 

                tClient.addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress( 
                        InetAddress.getByName(hostPort[0]), Integer.parseInt(hostPort[1]))); 
            } 
            this.client = tClient; 

        } catch (Exception e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
    } 
    return this.client; 
}
```

This client code runs but when executing the below code : 
              this.getClient().prepareGet(indexName, typeName, String.valueOf(id)).get();

The exception is thrown:

```
NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available: []] 
        at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(TransportClientNodesService.java:280) 
        at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:197) 
        at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.support.TransportProxyClient.execute(TransportProxyClient.java:55) 
        at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.doExecute(TransportClient.java:272) 
        at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:347) 
        at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:85) 
        at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:59) 
        at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.get(ActionRequestBuilder.java:67)
```

I have also tried using IPAddress instead of host name. The above code runs properly if

esnode is mapped to 127.0.0.1

Can somebody help...

Comment: Have you read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23521094/3219121) ?

Answer (score 1):

Setup elasticsearch host ip address to network.host value in elasticsearch.yml

network.host: es_host_ip

This is solve TransportClient NoNodeAvailableException issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your elasticsearch server have also version 2.0, if no, upgrade. Client and server must have the same version to work, I don't know why but this solved my problem.

Cheers,

Comment: Client and server are of same versions and  is working for 127.0.0.1. But not working for any other IP Address(ES node available in network).

Comment: Is something wrong with ES configuration.  
Followiing config is used:  
**cluster.name: esearch**   
**http.port: 9200**  
Only above two properties are set explicitly in config. For rest default is used.

Answer (score 0):

Other reason could be, your *Elasticsearch Java client* is a different version from your *Elasticsearch server*.

Elasticsearch Java client version is nothing but your elasticsearch jar version in your code base.

For example: In my code it's **elasticsearch-2.4.0.jar**

To verify Elasticsearch server version,

> $ /Users/kkolipaka/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -version Version:
>   5.2.2, Build: f9d9b74/2017-02-24T17:26:45.835Z, JVM: 1.8.0_111

As you can see, I've downloaded latest version of Elastic server 5.2.2 but forgot to update the ES Java API client version 2.4.0 https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/client.html