# Elasticsearch 2.x sometimes throws NoNodeAvailableException

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have the [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23520684/elasticsearch-java-apinonodeavailableexception-no-node-available/), but it doesn't always happen, lets say:

- try connection. It fail
- try connection. It fail
- try connection. It works...

sometime I'm lucky and it works for a couple of weeks

I don't use spring-boot, jars and server are the same es-version (2.1.1. I tried 2.4.0 too, and an older es-version is not a solution). Cluster name and port are well. Curl commands and Sense are working too

my elasticsearch.yml:

```
cluster.name sugar
network.host: [my_host, _local_]
```

my java connection code:

```
Settings settings = Settings.settingsBuilder()
    .put("cluster.name", "sugar")
    .build();

InetAddress hostAddress = InetAddress.getByName("my_host");
Client client = TransportClient.builder()
    .settings(settings)
    .build()
    .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(hostAddress, 9300));

// for testing connection purpose
client.admin()
    .cluster()
    .prepareHealth()
    .execute();
    .actionGet();
```

we have a docker-container for QA, and it works always!, but our customers are using Windows, all of them, and linux is not an alternative...

I don't know if this is a firewall problem, Elasticsearch bug, or a ghost, but this is really rare

can anyone help me, please

thank you

Comment: I'm using right now elasticsearch 5.1.1 and the problem is gone