# Nonodeavailableexception :: Elascticsearch on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

We have our own 3 nodes cluster ES (v6.1.3) instance installed on AWS. When we are trying to connect it using a JAVA transport client we are getting NoNodeAvailableException. Even the 'telnet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 9300' says connected but no luck with Transport client. Already tried lot of things as mentioned in several blogs. Please suggest how to get it fixed. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Without knowing what you've tried, it's impossible to "suggest how to get it fixed." You need to show _exactly_ what you're doing to connect (that means code), and _exactly_ what is happening (that means exceptions with stack traces). Take a look at [this](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/nonodeavailableexception-cannot-connect-java-api-and-elasticsearch/25474) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23520684/elasticsearch-java-apinonodeavailableexception-no-node-available) to see how to ask a good question. In fact, I suspect that the answer to the second will answer your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ElasticSearch Java API:NoNodeAvailableException: No node available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23520684/elasticsearch-java-apinonodeavailableexception-no-node-available)

Comment: @kdgregory, thanks for your response, please see below details:  
1. **elasticsearch.yml**:  
cluster.name: es-cluster-name  
node.name: es-node-1  
network.host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (Private IP)  
http.port: 9200  
transport.tcp.port: 9300

Comment: 2. **transport client code**:
Settings settings = Settings.builder().put("cluster.name", "es-cluster-name").put("xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled", true).put("xpack.security.user","username:password").put("client.transport.ping_timeout", "5s").put("xpack.ssl.key", "es.key").put("xpack.ssl.certificate","es.crt").put("xpack.ssl.certificate_authorities","ca.crt").build();

PreBuiltXPackTransportClient client = new PreBuiltXPackTransportClient(settings);
TransportClient connection = client.addTransportAddress(new TransportAddress(new InetSocketAddress("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", 9300)));

Comment: @kdgregory, and here is the exception stacktrace:  
Exception in thread "main" NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{xZDe_hh6Si-uX5cJ7YGWWg}{xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx}{xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9300}]]
        at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(TransportClientNodesService.java:347)

Comment: Please don't put additional information in the comments, it's unreadable. Edit your question, and add the information inside code tags (you can select the text and click the "code" button in the editor). Also, you need the _entire_ stack trace, not just the exception. In almost all cases, the real problem is shown by a "caused by" message in the trace.